# What's the best way to measure air-core transformer and variable capacitor using an LCR

Tags: capacitor, transformer, lcr

In order to create a model I need to measure the capacitance of a variable capacitor and an air-core transformer. This is my first time dealing with old models of capacitors and inductors and I'm wondering what the best way to measure them is.

---

The LCR meter keeps giving me different values while measuring the variable capacitor, so my questions are:

1. Should I use the series or parallel equivalent circuit since I expect values around 200pF?
2. Should it be connected to the voltage source or not?
3. Will it be affected by the surrounding whether it is an iron box or generator or another capacitor?
4. Where is the best physical place to place the probes?

[image: rotary capacitor]

[image: Air-coil Transformer]

Comment: Do you mean how to calculate the L and C values?

Comment: yes the values of L for the transformer, and the values of C for the Variable capacitor

Comment: What @rdtsc asked was if you want to _measure_ or _calculate_ it. To measure it, you hook up your LCR meter to it. To calculate it, you either have a formula or a FEM analysis.

Comment: Also, that appears to be an inductor, not a transformer.